# Points should not be connected in plotly line charts if there is a data gap - possible?

Tags: python, charts, plotly

I am using the plotly library to create charts. I have a weather data which gets updated every one hour for every day. Say due to device fault, the current data did not get updated for a particular day and instead the old data is updated. The plotly by default will just draw a line for points given and make charts. If there is a data gap (i.e if there is no data for some hours) , it should not link those points.Is it possible using plotly?

Comment: Check the data for gaps and define different datasets.

Dataset 1 till gap occurs.
Dataset 2 where you get data again

Comment: It should check whether difference in time is 1 hour between two records, if the difference is not 1hour it should not link the points and if the difference is same, it should link points and draw line. But both  linked line and not linked points should be in same color representing a single class in the legend.

Answer (score 1):

A hacky way to do it would be to insert a null point when you have a gap. It will create a discontinuity in the line.

However, this means adding points to the graph so if you have a lot of gaps, this may impact the performances.

See this [snippet](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKkWRz):

```
Plotly.plot( TESTER, [{
    x: [1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 5],
    y: [1, 2, 4, null, 8, 16] }], { 
    margin: { t: 0 } } );
```